# Why isn't bower package's file included in git?

Tags: git, bower

I created a custom bower package that is not yet released yet. I included it in my bower_components folder, and the folder of the package does appear when I pull from the repo, yet the content (files) are not. There is only an empty package folder in the bower_components folder. Does git do this by default? How should I prevent it?

If i look at the repo, my package folder appears to be a binary file instead of a folder

Comment: So the package appear and the files that are inside not? Maybe a gitinore inside the folder? check it. If not make a git add . (. take the files inside the folders).

Comment: @not gitignore file, and already did the basics including `git add .`

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer if i look at the repo, my package folder appears to be a binary file instead of a folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically due to your bower package contains .git, so git sees the folder as a file instead of a folder. To fix this, you will first remove the bower package, commit, and then add it again after making sure the .git isn't in it anymore.